# Javascript methods and copies

Tags: javascript, methods, copy

When you create a method in a constructor function like this:

```
var Something = function() {
    this.doSomething = function() {/* do something here */};
};
```

Javascript will make a copy of `doSomething` each time you create a new object with the `Something` constructor function.
But when you do it like this:

```
var Something = function() {

};
Something.prototype.doSomething = function() {/* Do something here */};
```

Does javascript still make a copy of `doSomething` each time you create an object with the `Something` constructor function, Or does `doSomething` in each object refer to the same thing for efficiency?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily test this yourself, just run:

```
var a = new Something();
var b = new Something();
console.log(a.doSomething === b.doSomething);
```

In the case when you are defining the method in prototype the console.log should print `true`.

Anyway for all things JavaScript I suggest browsing MDN as it gives avery good introduction on most any subject. CSS and HTML too.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain

Answer (score 0):

The `prototype` is an object and as such is a reference, appending a method to it allow you to have only one spot in memory with the method shared by all your instances, that's why is the preferred way to declare methods.

```
function Something(){ 
  //as many spot in memory as the number of instances
 this.doSomething = function(){

 }
};

//only one spot in memory 
Something.prototype.doSomething = function(){

}
```